# Php if, else not working

Tags: php, html

This is the code I am using within my html file

```
<? if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["gender"]) || empty($_POST["dorm"]): ?>
  You must provide your name, gender, and dorm!  Go <a href="froshims2.php">back</a>.
<? else: ?>
  You are registered!  (Well, not really.)
<? endif ?>
```

I get a error saying:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in
>   /home/jharvard/vhosts/localhost/public/week2/register2.php on line 20

I don't understand why this form of if else is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing closing bracket on this line

```
<? if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["gender"]) || empty($_POST["dorm"]): ?>
```

Should be

```
<? if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["gender"]) || empty($_POST["dorm"])): ?>
```

note the last bracket after `$_POST['dorm']`

Comment: Also `<? endif ?>` should be `<? endif; ?>`

Comment: semicolon is not necessary before php close tag

Comment: Thanks, yes the error was in the missing bracket on the if line

Comment: @MackieeE ["The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block."](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Comment: @MattGibson Noted =) Forgot to realise when even I do `<?=$row["somevar"]?>` sometimes! Apologies for that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing one `)` at the end of your if statement and a semicolon after `endif`:

```
<? if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["gender"]) || empty($_POST["dorm"])): ?>
  You must provide your name, gender, and dorm!  Go <a href="froshims2.php">back</a>.
<? else: ?>
  You are registered!  (Well, not really.)
<? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["gender"]) || empty($_POST["dorm"]): ?>` missing ) at end before :

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["gender"]) || empty($_POST["dorm"])) 
  echo 'You must provide your name, gender, and dorm!  Go <a href="froshims2.php">back</a>.';
else
  echo "You are registered!  (Well, not really.)";
?>
```